# Does a neighbourhood have to extend from the point $a$ to both directions equally?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

> The $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of a point "$a$" in $\mathbb R$ is defined as the set of points $x$ about a point "$a$" such that $|x-a|<\epsilon$, $\epsilon>0$.

But this means that the point "$a$" will be in the middle of the neighbourhood?

Comment: The definition by [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)#Definitions):

>If $X$ is a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) and $p$ is a point in $X$, a neighbourhood of $p$ is a subset $V$ of $X$ that includes an [open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) $U$ containing $p$

. So no.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. A neighborhood $N$ of $a$ must contain some interval $(a-r,a+r)$, with $r>0$. But $N$ doesn't have to have a middle point and, even if it has one, the middle point doesn't have to be $a$. For instance, $(1,+\infty)$ is a neighborhood of $2$.

Comment: Thanks, that does clear things up quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct to investigate this idea is a good one. As the subject develops, there are distinctions to be made, and the idea of a neighbourhood of a point becomes any open set containing it. A collection of open sets with appropriate properties is called a topology, and can be defined without any reference to distance.

What you have defined is best called an open ball around $x$ - because it is an open set containing $x$ it is a neighbourhood of $x$ and remains a neighbourhood as the definition and context change - it is the classic example of a neighbourhood in some ways. The definition of a ball does put $x$ at the centre.